# Implement Peek of RabbitMQ Queue

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

Am trying to implement peek of RabbitMQ queue. I tried to disable ack of RabbitMQ queue in a spring boot application but not able to do so. I am following this project https://github.com/Java-Techie-jt/springboot-rabbitmq-example but there is not much info on how to disable ack.

Is there any way to disable ack ?